React Native ViewManager getCommandsMap
When I have to communicate between native and rn, I have to list up command id and name on getCommandsMap of ViewManager. And then, I can receive the command from receiveCommand. I found out that receiveCommand method which has commendId of Int Type is deprecated, and It seems that only command name(String) makes communication work well.
My question is:

Is it okay to define any dummy int value on getCommandsMap as counterpart value of command name?
Why do ViewManager's getCommandsMap return type is Map<String, Int> ?

  /**
   * Subclasses of {@link ViewManager} that expect to receive commands through {@link
   * UIManagerModule#dispatchViewManagerCommand} should override this method returning the map
   * between names of the commands and IDs that are then used in {@link #receiveCommand} method
   * whenever the command is dispatched for this particular {@link ViewManager}.
   *
   * @return map of string to int mapping of the expected commands
   */
  public @Nullable Map<String, Integer> getCommandsMap() {
    return null;
  }

@Deprecated
    public void receiveCommand(@NonNull T root, int commandId, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
    }

    public void receiveCommand(@NonNull T root, String commandId, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {

